# Как перезалить существующий проект в google play при изменении пакета?

Tags: android, google-play

Как перезалить существующий проект в google play?

Проблема в следующем: я поменял названия пакета (он ругается APK-пакет должен иметь название). Мне надо, чтобы пакет был изменен, т.к в названии пакета опечатка, но в консоли google play не возможно удалить приложения.
Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: никак, заливать новое приложение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> никак, заливать новое приложение

из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/586235/#comment784009_586235) @georgehardcore 3 ноября в 8:33